# How to extract lat and long from 2 csv's and plot 2 scatter_mapbox in one map using plotly, dropna?

Tags: python, plotly

I am using "fig.add_trace(fig2.data[0])" to merge 2 scatter_mapbox, it does show data of both csv but with same legends and same color.
I want data of both csv  on map with different colors and different legend. Also, need the ability to switch between data's at will.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and provide code showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Imported plotly.express and pandas lib. Read 1st csv in df and 2nd in df2. Used df.dropna for both df's. Used scatter_mapbox(fig & fig2) for two df's with lat, long, hover_name, hover_data, color, color discrete sequence,size,zoom,height and width as parameter res. Then fig.add_trace(fig2.data[0]). Used mapbox_style as open-street-map. I am getting data for both csv on map but with same color parameter for both csv's. I am not able to differentiate btwn 2 csv's info. Eg,1st csv has mcdonals store info and 2nd csv has wendy;s info, I want to see both together with their legends to differentiat